# How do I exit keyboard navigation mode?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, keyboard, accessibility, navigation

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I've run into a bit of an issue.

I was working on a program I'm writing and I believe I accidentally enabled a keyboard accessibility option. When I try to use my keyboard normally now, the tab key selects different elements of a GUI application and pressing space acts as if I'm clicking the selected element. It's getting rather annoying as I can't use my desktop as I normally do, pressing these keys reasonably regularly.

Thank you.

Comment: You can disable that option https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y.html.en

Comment: @ChanganAuto it has shortcuts I can use whilst its on but I can't find anything on that page about how to turn it off

Comment: Is it not sufficient to place your cursor back in your text? What you describe is normal keyboard support in UI elements such as dialogs. What is the application where you have the issue?

Comment: @vanadium It's just my whole desktop, discord does it, any webpage on firefox does it. Firefox also has a flashing line when I click on any element as if it's a text field.